# Full Site link on Mobile Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Reaching out to the community here for a best practice/best implementation question.

I am using MVC3 in a major project, the MVC3 site will handle both our full site as well as our mobile site in a single solution. I have created a custom view engine to handle mapping mobile requests to the appropriate mobile views.

A requirement that popped up recently is to have a "Full Site" link on the mobile portion of the site to allow a mobile user to view the full site (actually to be able to switch back and forth).

Anyone have any insight on a possible quick solution or done something similiar?

I have a separate layout file (master page) for my mobile views that the "Full Site" link appears on.

Thanks in advance for any possible answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could go. A couple ideas:

1. Store a cookie when the user clicks "View Classic" or "View Mobile" that your custom view engine can check before directing to the appropriate view.
2. Take a look at the [51Degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) .NET library that handles mobile detection and redirection. There is a feature that can be used to track a user's preference (see firstRequestOnly config option). Steve Sanderson has a good blog overview on implementing this library in MVC3: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/

Comment: Thanks on the heads up on the 51Degrees library, I will definitely be using this for better mobile browser detection at a minimum.

Comment: Again, I cannot thank you enough for mentioning the 51Degrees library. It is absolutely great!!

Answer (score 1):

This should be something like a parameter for sure, view engine needs to know about the user preference. So it chooses the default view as it does now, but checks some parameter if the user preference does not match the default option.

Cookie, URL param...

Comment: Yeah, I have it working with setting a cookie now and then checking the cookie from my custom mobile view engine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you're asking how to link the two "versions" of the site, wouldn't it be as "simple" as having two `Areas`?

Each area will define its own routes, with the mobile area starting its routes with, for instance:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "Mobile_Default",
        "mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

so it's quite easy to link from one area to the other:

```
@Html.ActionLink("non-mobile site", "index", "home", new { area = "" }, null)
```

and the other way round:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mobile site", "index", "home", new { area = "mobile" }, null)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, you mention having both the Full and mobile sites in a single solution. How do you keep them separated (the bits that need be, that is) if it's not with areas?

Comment: Separated by folders. So for every view folder, there is a corresponding "Mobile" folder inside of it that contains the mobile views. There can also be sub folders under the "Mobile" folder that are mobile device specific, like "IPhone", etc. If there is no "device specific" view available, it servers up the "Mobile" view.